# ExpressionType.Quote

Tags: linq, expression

What is the purpose of this UnaryExpression, and how should it be used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It takes an `Expression` object and wraps it with another `Expression`. For instance, if you have an expression which is for a lambda, using it in the tree will create a lambda expression, but using it quoted will result in an expression for a lambda in the output.

```
method                                 | resulting object                   | after compile
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Expression.Lambda(...                  | Expression of lambda               | Lambda
Expression.Quote(Expression.Lambda(... | Expression of expression of lambda | Expression of lambda
```